# Greek letters, symbols, and line breaks inside a ggplot legend label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to

1. have line breaks (automatic or forced)
2. justify the text (left or both left and right)
3. have greek letters and percentage signs

inside a gglot legend label.

I have experimented with several methods, but I don't seem to be able to combine all the tricks I read about.

I can get linebreaks by inserting `\n` into the labels, but that doesn't seem to work with greek letters, not inside legend labels. Or I could have linebreaks and greek letters in a base plot by combining `mtext()` and `bquote()` to insert a piece of text into the plot, (**EDIT**) but as pointed out by Gregor in the comments section, this doesn't work with `ggplot`. Below I combine a `list` with `paste0()` to pass text to the legend labels: the problem is I can't find the way to insert Greek letters, e.g. gamma.

Grateful for suggestions.

Here is a MWE with one of my attempts (**Edit:** improved MWE):

```
label1.line1 <- "Not much to say about this one"
label2.line1 <- "blabla blabla, blabla blabla, blee blee blee (bling, bling, bling),"
label2.line2 <- paste0("(", "1900-2014: g = 1.50%, gamma = 2.75%, and r = 2.30%",")")
label3.line1 <- "blabla blabla, blabla blabla, blee blee blee (bling, bling, bling),"
label3.line2 <- paste0("(", "1900-2014: g = 2.50%, gamma = 1.75%, and r = 2.30%",")")
labels_fixed <- list(
    label1.line1, 
    paste0(label2.line1, "\n", label2.line2),
    paste0(label3.line1, "\n", label3.line2)
)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)  # provides unit() function used to tweak spacing inside legend

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, group = factor(cyl), colour = factor(cyl), shape = factor(cyl))) + 
geom_line() + geom_point(size = 3) + theme_bw() + 
scale_shape_manual(name = "Details", values = c(17, 21, 15), 
    labels = labels_fixed) + 
scale_colour_manual(name = "Details", values = c("darkred", "darkgreen", "darkblue"), 
    labels = labels_fixed) + 
theme(legend.key = element_blank(), 
      legend.position = c(.65, .8), 
      legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), 
      legend.key.size = unit(2, "lines"), 
      legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

A minor problem is that the legend text is much smaller with multiple lines so the legend line spacing will need to be tweaked: I was able to tweak `legend.key.size` and `legend.text` to achieve a better result than the default, which is too cramped.

I also tried another suggestion involving `cat(strwrap("long label here"), sep = "\n")`, but I couldn't get that to work. I also tried `atop` but that makes each line much too small and the nesting required to achieve the desired stacking is tedious.

Is there any way to get Greek letters?

[image]

Here are some useful suggestions I couldn't make to work, e.g. the combination of `mtext()` and `bquote()` is mentioned in 1 and 2:

1. [Expression and new line in plot labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549337/expression-and-new-line-in-plot-labels)
2. [Line break in expression()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression)
3. [Wrap horizontal legend across multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432646/wrap-horizontal-legend-across-multiple-rows)
4. [using expression(paste( to insert math notation into a ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507742/using-expressionpaste-to-insert-math-notation-into-a-ggplot-legend)
5. [ggplot2 two-line label with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223846/ggplot2-two-line-label-with-expression)
6. [How to annotate() ggplot with latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514612/how-to-annotate-ggplot-with-latex)
7. [Greek letters in ggplot annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987158/greek-letters-in-ggplot-annotate)

Comment: Base graphics functions (like `mtext`) are incompatible with grid graphics (like ggplots).

Comment: to get Greek letters and "\n", you probably want to use Unicode characters (maybe with a cairo device), or alternatively the tikzDevice

Comment: Thanks baptiste! I have answered my own question using your hint. Feel free to add suggestions and I'll accept your answer of course.

Comment: ``family="mono"`` (inside an ``element_text`` inside a theme) doesn't play well with unicode.

Comment: This one works ``title = element_text(family = "DejaVu Sans Mono")``

Comment: baptiste's suggestion to use ``tikzDevice`` is very nicely illustrated in Ben Bolker's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514612/how-to-annotate-ggplot-with-latex/34372474

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Baptiste's suggestion was spot on: unicode go a long way. Replace every instance of gamma above with `\u03B3` and it will display as Greek. Amazing!

Printing can be done with the `cairo` device ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768176/unicode-characters-in-ggplot2-pdf-output)):

```
library(Cairo)
cairo_pdf(file = "ggplot-greek.pdf", width = 8, height = 5)
## ggplot object created here
dev.off()
```

Also works: `ggsave("greek.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)`

Here is a selection of unicode symbols I have found useful:

```
"\U016B" = ū
"\U016A" = Ū
"\U00FB" = û
"\U00DB" = Û
"\U0233" = ȳ
"\U0232" = Ȳ
"\U0177" = ŷ
"\U0176" = Ŷ
"\U0113" = ē
"\U0112" = Ē
"\u00EA" = ê
"\U00CA" = Ê
"\U003BC\U2080" = μ₀
"\U003BC\U2081" = μ₁
"R\U00B2" = R²
"\u221E" = ∞
"\u2248" = ≈
"\U2260" = ≠ 
"\u03C3/\u221An" = σ/√n
```

Sadly, not all special characters have a unicode equivalent. For instance, there is a unicode for y-hat but not for x-hat. It is possible to combine the letter x with a unicode bar, as in `"x\u0305" = x̅` or `"p\u0302" = p̂`, but that doesn't seem to print very well.

I have also had difficulty printing greek unicode as axis labels, so in these cases I resorted to `annotate()` with the option `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` to ensure that the labels printed below the axes do not get clipped ("on" is the default clipping behaviour).

Sometimes you can directly use the character, for instance:

```
myplot + labs(title  = "±")
```

When unicode fails, you can try `expression()`, e.g. `x̄`:

```
title = expression(paste("z = (", bar(x), "-\u03BC)/(\u03C3/\u221An)", sep = ""))  
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + labs(title = title) + theme_bw()
```

[image: title]

For convenience, I copy some commonly used greek letters' unicodes below. Many more unicodes may be found, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

```
\u0391  Α   Greek Capital Letter Alpha
\u0392  Β   Greek Capital Letter Beta
\u0393  Γ   Greek Capital Letter Gamma
\u0394  Δ   Greek Capital Letter Delta
\u0395  Ε   Greek Capital Letter Epsilon
\u0396  Ζ   Greek Capital Letter Zeta
\u0397  Η   Greek Capital Letter Eta
\u0398  Θ   Greek Capital Letter Theta
\u0399  Ι   Greek Capital Letter Iota
\u039A  Κ   Greek Capital Letter Kappa
\u039B  Λ   Greek Capital Letter Lambda
\u039C  Μ   Greek Capital Letter Mu
\u039D  Ν   Greek Capital Letter Nu
\u039E  Ξ   Greek Capital Letter Xi
\u039F  Ο   Greek Capital Letter Omicron
\u03A0  Π   Greek Capital Letter Pi
\u03A1  Ρ   Greek Capital Letter Rho
\u03A3  Σ   Greek Capital Letter Sigma
\u03A4  Τ   Greek Capital Letter Tau
\u03A5  Υ   Greek Capital Letter Upsilon
\u03A6  Φ   Greek Capital Letter Phi
\u03A7  Χ   Greek Capital Letter Chi
\u03A8  Ψ   Greek Capital Letter Psi
\u03A9  Ω   Greek Capital Letter Omega
\u03B1  α   Greek Small Letter alpha
\u03B2  β   Greek Small Letter beta
\u03B3  γ   Greek Small Letter gamma
\u03B4  δ   Greek Small Letter delta
\u03B5  ε   Greek Small Letter epsilon
\u03B6  ζ   Greek Small Letter zeta
\u03B7  η   Greek Small Letter eta
\u03B8  θ   Greek Small Letter theta
\u03B9  ι   Greek Small Letter iota
\u03BA  κ   Greek Small Letter kappa
\u03BB  λ   Greek Small Letter lambda
\u03BC  μ   Greek Small Letter mu
\u03BD  ν   Greek Small Letter nu
\u03BE  ξ   Greek Small Letter xi
\u03BF  ο   Greek Small Letter omicron
\u03C0  π   Greek Small Letter pi
\u03C1  ρ   Greek Small Letter rho
\u03C2  ς   Greek Small Letter final sigma
\u03C3  σ   Greek Small Letter sigma
\u03C4  τ   Greek Small Letter tau
\u03C5  υ   Greek Small Letter upsilon
\u03C6  φ   Greek Small Letter phi
\u03C7  χ   Greek Small Letter chi
\u03C8  ψ   Greek Small Letter psi
\u03C9  ω   Greek Small Letter omega
```

Information about which fonts to use with unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Unicode_fonts

Some currency symbols:

```
# http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm
Character   Name    Browser     Image
\u0024  DOLLAR SIGN     $
\u00A2  CENT SIGN   ¢
\u00A3  POUND SIGN  £
\u00A4  CURRENCY SIGN   ¤
\u00A5  YEN SIGN    ¥
\u058F  ARMENIAN DRAM SIGN
\u060B  AFGHANI SIGN    ؋
\u09F2  BENGALI RUPEE MARK  ৲
\u09F3  BENGALI RUPEE SIGN  ৳
\u09FB  BENGALI GANDA MARK
\u0AF1  GUJARATI RUPEE SIGN     ૱
\u0BF9  TAMIL RUPEE SIGN    ௹
\u0E3F  THAI CURRENCY SYMBOL BAHT   ฿
\u17DB  KHMER CURRENCY SYMBOL RIEL  ៛
\u20A0  EURO-CURRENCY SIGN  ₠
\u20A1  COLON SIGN  ₡
\u20A2  CRUZEIRO SIGN   ₢
\u20A3  FRENCH FRANC SIGN   ₣
\u20A4  LIRA SIGN   ₤
\u20A5  MILL SIGN   ₥
\u20A6  NAIRA SIGN  ₦
\u20A7  PESETA SIGN     ₧
\u20A8  RUPEE SIGN  ₨
\u20A9  WON SIGN    ₩
\u20AA  NEW SHEQEL SIGN     ₪
\u20AB  DONG SIGN   ₫
\u20AC  EURO SIGN   €
\u20AD  KIP SIGN    ₭
\u20AE  TUGRIK SIGN     ₮
\u20AF  DRACHMA SIGN    ₯
\u20B0  GERMAN PENNY SIGN   ₰
\u20B1  PESO SIGN   ₱
\u20B2  GUARANI SIGN    ₲
\u20B3  AUSTRAL SIGN    ₳
\u20B4  HRYVNIA SIGN    ₴
\u20B5  CEDI SIGN   ₵
\u20B6  LIVRE TOURNOIS SIGN     ₶
\u20B7  SPESMILO SIGN   ₷
\u20B8  TENGE SIGN  ₸
\u20B9  INDIAN RUPEE SIGN   ₹
\u20BA  TURKISH LIRA SIGN   ₺
\u20BB  NORDIC MARK SIGN    ₻
\u20BC  MANAT SIGN  ₼
\u20BD  RUBLE SIGN  ₽
\uA838  NORTH INDIC RUPEE MARK
\uFDFC  RIAL SIGN   ﷼
\uFE69  SMALL DOLLAR SIGN   ﹩
\uFF04  FULLWIDTH DOLLAR SIGN   ＄
\uFFE0  FULLWIDTH CENT SIGN     ￠
\uFFE1  FULLWIDTH POUND SIGN    ￡
\uFFE5  FULLWIDTH YEN SIGN  ￥
\uFFE6  FULLWIDTH WON SIGN
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! For other symbols (I was looking for the Danish Krone myself), is a list [here](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php). Just don't forget the `\u` etc.

Comment: @RobertMc, Thanks & sorry that the Danish Krone was not included in my list. Feel free to add it in! :-)

Comment: ``\u2248 = ≈``. See also 130 pages of unicode symbols you did not know you needed here: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf

Comment: And the list goes on: ``ℕ = "\u2115"``, ``ℤ = "\u2124"``, ``ℚ = "\u211a"``, ``ℝ = "\u211d"``, ``ℂ = "\u2102"``, ``≤ = "\u2264"``, ``≥ = "\u2265"``, ``∈ = "\u2208"``, ``∉ = "\u2209"``, ``∅ = "\u2205"``, ``∞ = "\u221e"``

Comment: For ggplot in the y-axis label this worked for me:   ylab(paste("Average phloem ring distance (","\U003bc","m)")) to give units in micrometers.

Comment: You can actually simplify that even further by removing the `paste()` and just typing `labs(y="Average phloem ring distance \u03BCm")`....you don't need to put the unicode character in separately.