# Use Greek characters in ggplot2 titles / legend titles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a `ggtitle` for my chart which contains Greek characters: "Rate (kΩ)".  I also want to label the legend appropriately as "kΩ", presumably using `labs()`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2), which seemingly discusses use for every plot section *except* the ones above.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `expression()` for any of the arguments to `labs()`, of which `title=` is one.

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle(expression(Rate~k*Omega)) + 
  labs(x=expression(k*Omega), colour=expression(k*Omega)) `.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to use `labs`to label **both** your main title, and your legend. It's probably personal preference, but I do find it just a bit tidier.

Eipi mentioned about `expression` and he's right, all you needed was to wrap that part of the code in brackets to get what you asked for: `Rate (kΩ)`

The full code would be something like this:

```
ggplot(smr, aes(Fuel.Rate, Eng.Speed.Ave.)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title=expression(Rate~(k*Omega)), x=expression(k*Omega))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. For a unicode solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690729/greek-letters-symbols-and-line-breaks-inside-a-ggplot-legend-label